# Дублятся заголовки вопросов в разделе "Отзывы на сообщение" инструментов модератора

Tags: дефект, инструменты-модератора, 10k-tools

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/post-feedback/underrated?filter=all

После нажатия на "показать вопрос полностью":

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С ответами такой проблемы нет.

Comment: Метка не та. Надо про 10к

Comment: У меня раздвоений нет, кстати. Какие браузер, ОС?

Comment: @älёxölüt Firefox/Win7. Дублится только на вопросах.

Comment: [Хром под андроид проблемы не наблюдаю](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Isi.jpg). Под FF так же.

Comment: @älёxölüt нажмите "показать вопрос полностью".

Comment: А ... блин. Там ещё надо нажать "показать вопрос полностью"

Comment: Короче, это надо на MSE переносить

Comment: @älёxölüt у меня на англоязычных сайтах репы нет, чтоб скрины сделать, а к ru постам они прохладны.

Comment: Дарю [https://meta.stackexchange.com/tools/post-feedback/underrated?filter=all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQCcQ.png) :)

Comment: @älёxölüt спс https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323141/260198 (:

Comment: ссылка почему на SO? Я ж привел в коммент на MSE :)

Comment: @älёxölüt fixed ^^"